# Countable quotient space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, quotient-spaces

I know the quotient space $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Q}$ has the trivial topology. I'm thinking on an example of a quotient such that $\mathbb{R} / A$ is infinite enumerable and still have the trivial topology. Do you have any example of this? Thank you all.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}/A$ to you? Quotient as in subset collapse? As in $x\sim y$ iff $x=y$ or $x,y\in A$? In that case $\mathbb{R}/(\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q})$ is countably trivial.

Comment: @freakish unless I'm very confused, I don't think that is a trivial topology. There are lots of non empty open sets, for example if U is the complement of 0. (U's preimage is the complement of zero in R, so open, so U is open in the quotient topology...)

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = \mathbb{R}$. Then $\mathbb{R} / A$ is a point, and so it has the trivial topology and is countable.

Update: Seems like you are asking about group quotient. Here is a construction:

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $V$ denote the subspace $\mathbb{Q}$ (so that we know that it is topologically dense), and pick $E$ to be a subspace containing $V$ of codimension one. (We need Zorn's lemma to guarantee the existence of a maximal element in the poset of subsets containing $V$.)

Then $\mathbb{R} / E$ is a one dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. In particular, it is countable. Moreover, it is a quotient of $\mathbb{R}/ V$ (by $E / V$), which has the trivial topology. So it has the trivial topology.

Comment: I wasn't specific enough, so I edited the question. I already thought about this case, I want the quotient to be also an infinite set. Thanks by the way for your answer.

Comment: @Cat14 actually are you sure that R/Q has the trivial topology? What about the open set that is the complement of the square root of two.

Comment: @AreaMan what open set you refer exactly? One assures the triviality of the topology because of the density. In fact one can find a representant of every equivalence class (by the relation $a\sim b$ whenever $a-b\in\mathbb{Q}$) in any open interval $(x,y)$ so topology must be trivial on the quotient.

Comment: @Tan1278 so you are using the group quotient, not the topological quotient. That's worth clarifying. so when you ask for an A to quotient by, you actually want a subgroup A...

Comment: @Tan1278 ok, try this: consider R as a vector space over Q, and let A be the (underlying abelian group) of a codimension one subspace that contains the subspace Q.

Comment: @Tan1278 btw you need zorns lemma in the construction I just gave you.

Comment: @Tan1278 does that make sense to you? I put more details in an updated answer.